# Command-Line tool to find large files on a Linux system

Tags: python, file-system, console, linux

Is the code pythonic and easy to read and understand? Is there a better way to exclude directories? Did I miss any bugs?

```
'''Find large files on a linux system.

:Example:
excludes = ['/proc', '/sys', '/dev', '/swapfile']
find_larg_files('/', n_results=20, excludes=excludes)
'''

import os
import operator
from itertools import islice
import fnmatch
import re
import argparse


def take(number, iterable):
    """Return first n items of the iterable as a list.

    :param number: `int` How many do you want to take.
    :param iterable: `iterable`
    :rtype: `list`
    """
    return list(islice(iterable, number))


def walk(fpath, **kwargs):
    ''' Traverse thru a directory tree.

    :param fpath: `int` The root file path
    :param excludes: `list` optional directories to exclude
    :rtype: `generator`
    '''
    kwargs.setdefault('excludes', [])
    excludes = kwargs.get('excludes')
    # transform glob patterns to regular expressions
    excludes = r'|'.join([fnmatch.translate(x) for x in excludes]) or r'$.'
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fpath, topdown=1):
        # exclude dirs
        if excludes:
            dirs[:] = [os.path.join(root, d) for d in dirs]
            dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not re.match(excludes, d)]
        for name in files:
            yield os.path.join(root, name)


def getsize(fpath):
    ''' Return the size of a file.
    Will return 0 if an OSError is raised.
    :param fpath: `str` 
    ''' 
    try:
        return os.path.getsize(fpath)
    except OSError:
        return 0


def find_larg_files(fpath, n_results=10, **kwargs):
    ''' Recursively find the largest files in a directory.

    return n largest files in a directory tree.
    :param fpath: `str` where to start.
    :param n_results: `int` how many results to retrun.
    :param kwargs: This will be passed to walk.
    :rtype: `None` it prints the paths and sizes to the screen.
    '''
    results = {}
    for name in walk(fpath, **kwargs):
        results[name] = getsize(name)

    results = reversed(sorted(results.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
    for name, size in take(n_results, results):
        print name, size

def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Find large files')
    parser.add_argument('path', metavar='-p', type=str, help='The path to start crawling')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--results', metavar='-n', type=int,
        help='How many results to return the default is 10.',
        default=10
        )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--exclude', metavar='-e', type=list,
        help='Directoris to exclude in the search.',
        nargs='+', default=[]
        )

    args = parser.parse_args()
    find_larg_files(args.path, n_results=args.results, excludes=args.exclude)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: One comment on efficiency: instead of picking the largest `n` from the complete list, an alternative approach would be to only keep the largest `n` as you go.  For really huge collections of files this could make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Some observations:

- Use a `main` function and <strike>the `argparse` module</strike> pull out an argument parsing method to make this scriptable.
- "larg" should be "large"; `getsize` should be `get_size`, `fpath` should be `file_path`. Saving characters costs a lot of money in maintainability.
- As [@Edward wrote](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171304/command-line-tool-to-find-large-files-on-a-linux-system#comment324598_171304), don't keep the entire list of files in memory. As a counter-point I would have liked for the results limit to not exist - the default behaviour would then be simpler to implement, and would return every file in order of size.
- In addition to excluding directories you should make sure that you don't follow symbolic links, or you could end up with an infinite loop.
- The `OSError` in this case should be fatal - it indicates that your program is faulty since it doesn't properly filter files which you can't get the size of. I believe it could also happen if a file is not accessible, which means any result you get from this script might be inaccurate.
- Replace `**kwargs` with `excludes=None`, followed by a simple `excludes = [] if excludes is None else excludes`. That way the parameter list is unambiguous. Even easier, make `excludes` mandatory (you are always using it anyway). YAGNI & KISS apply :)
- It looks like your handling of exclusions doesn't anchor the regex at the start of the filename, so you'll end up excluding for example `/home/user/dev`.
- `excludes` in `walk` is always truthy. You should either remove the `or r'$.'` bit (best option IMO) or get rid of `if excludes:`.
- You *reuse* `excludes` in `walk` to create a completely different list. This is a bad practice because it makes the use and content of a variable really hard to follow. Use separate variables for these.

Comment: I posted the wrong version i already added argparse

Comment: The `OSError` could be non-fatal, as the filename may disappear between the time of reading the directory and processing the names found therein.

Comment: @TobySpeight That's a good caveat, and should probably be a special case. I wouldn't include it in version 0.1, but it should definitely be handled by 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Sme remarks

- Seperate the functions: The function doing the walking also handles the arguments, so as @l0b0 suggest. I would have `find_larg_files` yield the results, and let `main` take care of the printing. That way you can reuse it
- I prefer `pathlib.Path` over `os.path`. That provides a lot of what you want to do out-of-the-box: `.rglob('*')` for the walking, `.is_file()` to check whether it exists and is a regular file, `.stat().st_size` for the size
- `sorted` has a `reverse` keyword

Just out of curiosity and because I might need something like this later, I made a SortedLimitedMapping

```
class SortedLimitedMapping:
    def __init__(self, items, maxlen, descending=True):
        """
        Some kind of sorted mapping with a maximum length.
        Sort order is standard sort-order of the (key, value)tuples
        Duplicate keys are permitted, as long as the corresponding values are sortable

        items can be a dict or a collection of (key, value) tuples
        """
        self._maxlen = maxlen
        self.descending = descending
        self._data = []

        self.add_items(items)


    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        #         print(f'adding {key, value}')
        data_to_add = (key, value)
        if len(self._data) < self.maxlen:
            self._data.append(data_to_add)
        else:
            old_min = min(self._data) if self.descending else max(self._data)
            if (old_min < data_to_add) == self.descending:
                new_data = self._data.copy()
                new_data.remove(old_min)
                new_data.append(data_to_add)
                try:
                    sorted(new_data)
                    self._data = new_data
                except TypeError as e:
                    raise ValueError(f'can not sort {data_to_add} in {self}') from e

    def add_items(self, items):
        if isinstance(items, dict):
            items = items.items()

        for key, value in items:
            self[key] = value

    @property
    def maxlen(self):
        return self._maxlen

    @maxlen.setter
    def maxlen(self, maxlen):
        self._data = self.data[:maxlen]
        self._maxlen = maxlen

    def __iter__(self):
        for key, value in self.data:
            yield key, value

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'SortedLimitedMapping({self.data}, maxlen={self.maxlen}, descending={self.descending})'

    @property
    def data(self):
        return sorted(self._data, reverse=self.descending)

    @property
    def keys(self):
        return (i[0] for i in self.data)

    @property
    def values(self):
        return (i[1] for i in self.data)

    def copy(self):
        return SortedLimitedMapping(items=self.data, maxlen=self.maxlen, descending=self.descending)

    def __copy__(self):
        return self.copy()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, SortedLimitedMapping):
            raise TypeError(f'SortedLimitedMapping only compares to SortedLimitedMapping, not to {type(other)}')
        if self.maxlen != other.maxlen:
            return False
        if self.descending != other.descending:
            return False
        return sorted(self._data) == sorted(other._data)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)
```